# Controlling access to classes in a JAR

Tags: java, class, jar

Alright, so I am writing a JAR to be the back end implementation of an instant messenger system.  In order to get the classes to interact and all, I am using `public class MyClassHere { ... }`.  But when I compile all the classes into the JAR, I don't want any class to be accessible except the main class.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to use a tool like [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#application) in your build chain to stop exposing everything outside your main class.

Comment: How would I configure ProGuard to do that?  I'll do some searching on it, but I've never used it before.

Comment: The first example on that linked page, basically, which only preserves the main function and hides/obfuscates/renames/optimizes everything else.

Comment: I'm not having a main function though, as this is just the implementation.  Basically I want to be able to take this JAR, code another program that calls the main file's constructor, and then can only touch the methods for that main class.

Comment: In that case, you should basically just replace the line `public static void main(java.lang.String[]);` in the example configuration with `public *`.

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, and slow, but in the constructor of these classes you could check the class where they are being instantiated from(using `new Exception.getStacktrace()`) - and limit control if called by anything except your class.

Comment: That would work for controlling the instantiation of the class, but I also don't want the methods of the class to be accessed either.  Implementing that on every method of almost every class on the server would be a bit of overhead

Comment: @Odiefrom Not every method - apart from the constructors, only the static methods you will have to add these checks. No object instantiated, no non-static methods can be called. But I agree, not very elegant.